# Using local Variables in _asm block in C

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I am writing a program in 16 bit Turbo C++ version 3.0 based on partial Assembly and C code. I have to use the local variables of C code in assembly block. I have debug the following code in Borland C++ 5 and MS VC++ 6. It works fine but these compilers are 32 bit therefore I have to do this in Turbo C. In Turbo C++ it displays an Error: "Invalid combination of opcode and oprends" the code is:

```
void AssignPixel (int X,int Y,int R,int G, int B )
{
_asm {
mov dx, 0x3c8
mov al, 4
out dx, al
inc dx
mov al, R   // ERROR
out dx, al
mov al, G   // ERROR
out dx, al
mov al, B   // ERROR
out dx, al

     mov ah , 0x0c 
     mov al , 4    
     mov cx , X  // ERROR
     mov dx , Y  // ERROR
     int       0x10 
}
```

Is there any way to use Variables with assembly code. Code Sample will be appreciated.

Comment: Would `mov al, [R]` work out? You might actually want `mov al, byte ptr [R]`.

Comment: ... why are you writing 16-bit code!?

Comment: @duskwuff smells like a homework, we were forced to write 16 bit code in ASM classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do these most likely because the sizes of the registers and variables don't match (8-bit vs 16-bit):

```
mov al, R
mov al, G
mov al, B
```

And here the assembler probably expects different syntax:

```
mov cx, X
mov dx, Y
```

Try these instead:

```
mov al, byte ptr [R] ; I don't remember if the brackets are required here
mov cx, [X]
```

Comment: This is not about local variables per se but about parameters passed from another function. Here you could declare the function naked and work directly with the cdecl ABI but this is quite a bit more messy and error prone

Comment: @doron: I know, this all is messy. I'd rather use an external asm subroutine or some better inline assembly (gcc's and Open Watcom's let you specify clobbered regs among the other things).

Answer (score 4):

In Turbo C assembly, variable names represent their addresses. So if you do

```
mov ax, R
```

you are loading the address of R (that is `&R`) into ax. But if you try:

```
mov al, R
```

you get an error, because addresses are 16 bits wide, and `al` register is 8 bits only.

If you write:

```
mov al, [R]
```

that is equivalent to:

```
mov al, byte ptr [R]
```

then you are loading the byte pointed to by `R` into the `al` register.
(The `byte ptr` thing is deduced automatically from the size of the known operand, in this case, `al`).

But note that the assembler know nothing about the types of your variables, so you are alone on that. For example, in your code, `R` is an integer (16 bits) but that last line loads only one byte. Since you are using a little endian machine, you are getting the least significant byte, that is equivalent to a cast to char, probably what you want.

Of course, if you need the whole value of R, just write:

```
mov ax, [R]
```

that is equivalent to:

```
mov ax, word ptr [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to use a local variable in assembly is leave code in a register. If you run out of registers, you have to move it to memory somewhere and then re-load it when you use it again.

A variable name is essentially a macro for where a variable is, which in implementation (for assembly purposes) is either a register or a slot in memory. HTH